# How to solve AttributeError : RNA_Types object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, scripting, error

I am using blender 2.82. When i add an addon it popup the AttributeError when i click on the checkbox. [image]

Comment: It's RNA type  plzz solve this error

Comment: Appears the Addon in question  requires conversion to 2.8x.   Groups from 2.7x and before have been replaced by collections. There will likely be other conversions required. Consult the home page of the addon.